# check if a point is on the route in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am able to show the route by taking the name of the place from user in google maps.now i want to check if the point lies on the route between two places that user have entered.i am using google maps javascript api v3 and `isLocationOnEdge()` is not working and polygon with two points is also not working.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two possibilities here , Google map has `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()`  checks if point with in polygon will return true
`google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()` checks point on or near a polyline and same for polygon. So i would suggest to use `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation()`.